# Percent Over Budget, Excel If statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

% Over Budget

How can I add another if statement so it will only return values if there is a value in D columns?

```
=IFERROR((D14-E14)/E14," ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `IFERROR` ...`=IF(OR(E14=0,ISBLANK(D14)),"","(D14-E14)/E14)`

With `IFERROR` ........`=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(D14),"",(D14-E14)/E14),"")`

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following methods would work for you.

Ignore blanks

```
=IF(D14="","",IFERROR((D14-E14)/E14," "))
```

Ignore text

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(D14),IFERROR((D14-E14)/E14," "),"")
```